# What is the kotlin("...") method in the Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

What is this `kotlin("...")` method described in Kotlin's "Using Gradle" tutorial? They mention [this syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm).

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
}
```

I see it used in more places too, not just the plugin. For example, it can be [used to get Kotlin dependencies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies).

```
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}
```

I have tried googling this but I'm having trouble finding results since Gradle uses a Kotlin DSL as well and the results for the two get mixed.

Running `gradle init --dsl kotlin --type kotlin-library` outputs the "normal" syntax *(see below for snipped output)* and I can't find documentation on this strange `kotlin("...")` piece about what it can and can't be used for. If I use the `kotlin("...")` approach as above it still works but I'm trying to figure out what it is and where it comes from.

```
plugins {
  // Apply the Kotlin JVM plugin to add support for Kotlin.
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.3.71"

  // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
  `java-library`
}

// ...

dependencies {
  // Align versions of all Kotlin components
  implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))

  // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

  // Use the Kotlin test library.
  testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

  // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
  testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an extension function provided by Gradle. It's distributed in `gradle-kotlin-dsl-<version>.jar!/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/KotlinDependencyExtensions.kt`. Find out more by Ctrl+clicking the function name in the IDE.

```
/**
 * Builds the dependency notation for the named Kotlin [module] at the given [version].
 *
 * @param module simple name of the Kotlin module, for example "reflect".
 * @param version optional desired version, unspecified if null.
 */
fun DependencyHandler.kotlin(module: String, version: String? = null): Any =
    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-$module${version?.let { ":$version" } ?: ""}"
```

Comment: This is the closest thing to source code I could find for it. Looks like this auto-generates that code. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/5e5c10e871bf1384def09ca379b4868f33cd9f9b/buildSrc/subprojects/kotlin-dsl/src/main/kotlin/codegen/GenerateKotlinDependencyExtensions.kt#L82-L89